# Returning the column header when the progressive difference of values in a row becomes <= 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have an Excel table with the initial stock for an item and the projected consumption based on the corresponding dates in the header. I would like to retrieve the date when there is going to be a shortage by calculating the progressive difference. I am showing only one row, but normally I have around 3000 lines. I would like to find a formula that returns the date of the shortage for every row.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is:

- add a column showing the shortage date:
  [image: capture 2]
- the date corresponds to when the stock will become negative (see picture for how I calculate that)
  [image: capture 3]

Comment: Please add a description and a screenshot of what you what to achieve, so that others can try to obtain that from your input data (please post more input data as well). Also, you mention an array but it is not clear where this array is. Add more details and a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: @simlev - I have added more info in my post. please let me know if now is clear. I have a series of consumption values (per date) that will be deducted from stock(Stock - Date1 - Date 2- Date 3, etc.). So I'm interested to see on which date the stock goes below 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can be done with a formula employing the likes of SUM, OFFSET and INDEX.
 However, I don't bother with complex formulas and resort to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> instead.

```
Sub DateOfShortage()
    StartLine = 2
    EndLine = 6
    StartColumn = 3
    EndColumn = 7

    For Line = StartLine To EndLine
        Stock = Cells(Line, 2)
        For Column = StartColumn To EndColumn
            Stock = Stock - Cells(Line, Column).Value
            If Stock <= 0 Then
                Cells(Line, EndColumn + 1).Value = Cells(1, Column).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Column
    Next Line
End Sub
```

Sample data and results:

[image]

---

If you add a *Calculation* line for every item, as shown in one of your screenshots, you can easily get the wanted date with an array formula (still looks too complex for my tastes):

[image]